# What's the policy on questions about the "best" way of doing X?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

An [edit](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/143) was just suggested to my question, replacing "What's the best way to ... ?" with "How to ... ?"

I approved the edit, since [SE automatically gives a warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/what-algorithm-does-stack-exchange-use-to-determine-if-a-question-may-be-subject) that questions containing "best" in the title might be subjective and liable to be closed. But on looking around a little, I discovered other questions asking about the "best" way of doing things: e.g. [What type of paint should I use to decorate a kitchen appliance?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/389/what-paint-is-best-to-decorate-a-kitchen-appliance) and [How do I choose which adhesive or material to repair action figures?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/26/how-do-i-choose-which-adhesive-or-material-to-repair-action-figures) The policy against questions about the "best" X presumably isn't absolutely SE-wide either, since there are entire SE sites dedicated to recommendation questions ([Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) and [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com)), so this looks like something for each site's community to decide independently.

**What should the Arts & Crafts SE policy be on questions about "the best way to do X"?**

Should we:

- close them as primarily opinion-based?
- allow them, perhaps with some kind of quality restriction?
- something else?

Comment: Fair point, I've edited my kitchen appliance question to be less "best"y :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at all possible, **edit them**.

"Best" is subjective. What's best depends on your situation, your needs, your wants, your resources, tastes, abilities and knowledge. What's best for me might not be best for you...

...But if you lay out *your* problem, *your* goals and *your* resources, folks might just be able to point you in the direction of a workable solution.

So ask for that.

[As prescribed by the venerable Help Center](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask),

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Any good question will draw its inspiration from someone's actual situation, a pressing need they wish to address. If you, the editor, can draw upon this and transform a "best practices" poll into a "what can solve my problem" question, *please* do so!

Yes, it's additional work and requires uncommon skills... But it is with these things that we strive to stand above The Barbarians of The Internet.

> **Khitan General:** But what is best in life?
>   **Khitan Warrior:** The open steppe, a fleet horse, falcons at your wrist, and the wind in your hair.
>   **Khitan General:** Wrong!
>   -- "Conan the Barbarian", via [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Conan_the_Barbarian_(1982_film))

Comment: I always want to give people the benefit of doubt when the word best is used. Usually there are better ways to narrow the question as you suggest anyway. With what I have seen you can almost always edit them or wait for some comments from the OP that could be easily used to narrow the question.

Comment: So I was wrong and this *is* an SE-wide rule?

Comment: "Ask real questions"? Yes, @Rand. "Don't use 'best'" isn't though; it's just a good idea if you want folks to think you're asking a real question.